# Update CRM DateTime Field | Daylight Saver | Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, datetime

I am attempting to populate Rewards Card Object in Salesforce CRM using AMPscript.

```
SET @CRMIssuancedate = Concat(FormatDate(StringToDate(@Issuancedate),'yyyy-MM-dd',''),'T',FormatDate(StringToDate(@Issuancedate),'','HH:mm:ss'),'+11:00')
```

I have managed to populate the date and time in the correct format with an offset of 11 hours by concatenating with Date and Time.

> Value passed to CRM: 2018-02-14T13:44:07+11:00
>
> Value in CRM: 14/02/2018 1:44 PM

The problem is the Daylight Saving which doesn't accomodate with the static offset.

Is there a way to automatically update the date and time field in CRM irrespective of when the Daylight Saving starts?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/LocalDateToSystemDate.htm ?

Comment: I did @Data_Kid and it didn't help. The fact that CRM needs an offset will be an issue when the Daylight Saver is on/off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help, I have figured this out. Generally the standard back-end time in SFMC is in CST and the timezone in Australia is AEST or AEDT depending on the Daylight saver.

The solution takes the difference between the AEDT and AEST to determine the daylight saver. Also depending on the difference the offset can be managed which then can be used to update the CRM date-time field in UTC.

Here is the code below:

```
%%[
SET @LocalDate = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now(1))
SET @SystemDate = Now(1)
SET @TimeDiff = DateDiff(@SystemDate,@LocalDate,'H')
SET @Offset = IIF(EMPTY(@TimeDiff),11,IIF(@TimeDiff==17,11,10))
]%%
```

The variable `@Offset` will output `11` during AEDT and `10` during AEST.